# Jetpack Compose state change not reflected across activities

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have an app with two activities. `Activity1` changes a `State` stored in a `ViewModel`, then starts `Activity2`. But somehow, the state change is only reflected in `Activity1`, not in `Activity2`.

**ViewModel**

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var hasChanged: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
}
```

**Composable of Activity1**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen1() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()

    Column {
        Text("State changed: " + viewModel.hasChanged.toString())
        Button(
            onClick = {
                viewModel.hasChanged = true
                startActivity(context, Intent(context, Activity2::class.java), null)
            }
        ) {
            Text("Change State!")
        }
    }
}
```

**Composable of Activity2**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen2() {
    val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
    Text("State changed: " + viewModel.hasChanged.toString())  # stays 'false'
}
```

**Behavior of the app**

- `Activity1` correctly shows the state to be `false`, initially
- After button is pressed, `Activity1` correctly displays the state to be `true`
- `Activity2` opens but still shows the state to be `false`

[image] [image] [image]

**Question**

Why is the state change not reflected in `Activity2` and can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewModels are unique to classes that implement `ViewModelStoreOwner`

```
@Composable
public inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> viewModel(
    viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner = checkNotNull(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current) {
        "No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner"
    },
    key: String? = null,
    factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory? = null,
    extras: CreationExtras = if (viewModelStoreOwner is HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory) {
        viewModelStoreOwner.defaultViewModelCreationExtras
    } else {
        CreationExtras.Empty
    }
```

`ComponentActivity` implements `ViewModelStoreOwner`, so it's a `ViewModelStoreOwner` that contains its own `ViewModel` instances and uses a `HashMap` to get same `ViewModel` for key provided as String.

```
val vm: MyViewModel = ViewModelProvider(owner = this)[MyViewModel::class.java]
```

This is how they are created under the hood. This here is Activity or Fragment depending on where ViewModelProvider's owner param is set at. In Compose ViewModelStore owner is accessed by `LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current`

You need to pass your `hasChanged` between `Activities` using `Bundle`, or have a Singleton repository or UseCase class that you can inject to both ViewModels or use local db or another methods to pass data between Activities.

Comment: can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73844235/11560810)

Comment: Thanks @Thracian, that sent me off in the right direction! I didn't realize that every activity would get its own ViewModel. Also, it seems that Jetpack Compose is designed to rather use a single activity. So I'm thinking about getting rid of the second one altogether.